# What's the probability of Joe winning a set of outcomes?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Joe is playing a game where he is given a bag one at a time and has to win the bag by drawing the corresponding color marble from the bag. There are 6 bags. Each bag is assigned a color that contains marbles of that color: The red bag has red marbles, the blue bag has blue marbles and so on.  Each bag also has a proportion of black marbles. If Joe draws from the red bag, he'll either get a red marble or a black marble.  If Joe gets a non-black marble from the bag, he "wins" the bag. If he draws a black marble, he doesn't win the color.

The proportion of color marbles in their respective bags are as follows.

```
{'Red': 0.25,
 'Blue': 0.30,
 'Purple': 0.15,
 'Green': 0.30,
 'Yellow': 0.30,
 'Orange': 0.20}
```

In this example, .25 of the marbles are Red and .75 are black.

**Winning outcomes** To win the game Joe has to win a set specific set of colors. Here is a minimum list of events where Joe can win.

```
[('red', 'purple', 'yellow'),
 ('red', 'yellow', 'blue'),
 ('orange', 'purple', 'yellow'),
 ('orange', 'yellow', 'blue'),
 ('purple', 'yellow', 'blue'),
 ('red', 'green', 'orange', 'yellow'),
 ('red', 'green', 'purple', 'blue'),
 ('red', 'orange', 'purple', 'blue'),
 ('green', 'orange', 'purple', 'blue')]
```

**Rules**:

- Joe is handed one bag at a time and the order of the bags is completely random.
- Joe draws only one marble from the bag he is handed.
- If Joe draws a non-black marble, he wins that color.
- The game ends when he earns a combination of bags that are contained in the winning outcomes list above or he draws black marbles from each bag.
- Joe only plays the game once.

The probability of each outcome is the intersection of the events, which can be found by taking the product of the events.

```
P(Red) * P(Purple) * P(Yellow)
=.25 *.15 * .30
```

and so on.

**Question**: What is the total probability that he gets any one of the outcomes and wins the game? I'm really struggling with this. I don't think it's the probability that exactly 1 event occurs.

```
P(exactly 1 occurs)= P(A and not B and not C)+ P(not A and B and not C)+ P(not A and not B and C)
```

The result of that method would seem like too low of a probability.

More to my confusion, if he draws from the red bag first and wins a red marble, but then draws from the purple bag and gets a black marble, then any winning outcome that contains a purple bag is eliminated from his winning outcomes list. In this example, if he draws a black marble from a purple bag, that eliminates five outcomes that he can win. (The outcome with purple, yellow, blue is NOT eliminated because Red, Purple, Yellow, Blue is a superset of purple, yellow, blue). I think this is the source of my confusion. My winning outcomes don't contain supersets so I might be missing data that otherwise would make this easier to understand.

How can I understand this?

Comment: This does not follow:  "In this example, .25 of the marbles are Red and .75 are black." (because you don't know how many marbles are in each bag. What if the purple bag had thousands and the other bags just dozens? (Fortunately, that is irrelevant.) Also - Joe might as well draw from all the bags simultaneously.

Comment: I agree it's irrelevant. Let's assume that each bag has 100 marbles.